# Postgresql: Random value for a column selected frm second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `drivers` and `drivers_names`. What I want is for every driver I select from the first table to have a random name from the second, but what I get is one name for all drivers in the result. Yes, it is different every time but is one for all. Here is my query, I'm using `postgresql`.

```sql
SELECT
    drivers.driver_id AS drivers_driver_id,
    (
        SELECT
            drivers_names.name_en
        FROM
            drivers_names
        ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1
    ) AS driver_name
FROM
    drivers
```

Result:

```
11  Denis
13  Denis
7   Denis
```

Tables structure.

**drivers**

```
+--------------+
| column_name  |
+--------------+
| driver_id    |
| property_1   |
| property_2   |
| property_3   |
+--------------+
```

**drivers_names**

```
+-------------+
| column_name |
+-------------+
| name_id     |
| name_en     |
+-------------+
```

Comment: if you will show structure of both the tables it will be helpful.

Comment: @HussainNagri I added the structures for both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres probably evaluates the subselect only once because technically there's no reason to evaluate it for every row.
You could force it by referencing a column from the drivers table into the subselect, like this:

```
SELECT
    drivers.driver_id AS drivers_driver_id,
    (
        SELECT
            drivers_names.name_en
        FROM
            drivers_names
        ORDER BY random()+drivers.driver_id LIMIT 1
    ) AS driver_name
FROM
    drivers
```

Comment: you can also put `random()+drivers.oid::integer` which may be a more general solution to all cases (my `id` was alphanumeric)